# extend an override method from abstract class in java

Tags: java

Here is my scenario:

```
public interface Father{ public void sayHi(); }
public abstract class FatherImpl implements Father{
   @Override
   public void sayHi() { System.out.print("Hi"); } }
```

then is the child

```
public interface Child{}
public class ChildImpl extends FatherImpl implements Child{}
```

and test function is

```
Child c = new ChildImpl();
c.sayHi();
```

This will throw compiling error. 
Only when i change child interface to

```
public interface Child{} extends Father
```

Then the program runs properly.

Anyone can help me explain the reason.

Comment: What a strange family.

Comment: remember when you declare Child c = new ChildImpl(), the reference type is Child, not ChildImpl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Child c = new ChildImpl();
```

The `Child` interface doesn't have a `sayHi()` method, that's in `ChildImpl`. You're referencing `c` as a `Child` object, so you can't access the method.

You could either reference the object as a `ChildImpl` or add another class.

```
ChildImpl c = new ChildImpl();
```

Or

```
public abstract class TalkingChild {
    @Override
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.print("Hi");
    }
}
```

Or

```
public interface TalkingChild {
    public void sayHi();
}
```

The best solution completely depends on your specific scenario.

Comment: how you have created a concrete method in an interface??

Comment: @10sw33 Oh god my bad. How did I miss that?

Comment: Thanks, Anubian. That really help me a lot, how come i forgot it declared as a Child but not ChildImpl.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler cares only the *declared* type - the type that is *assigned* is irrelevant.

Applying this to your case, the type `Child` has no methods. It doesn't consider that you assigned a `ChildImpl`, which *does* have a `sayHi()` method, to the `Child` variable.